# (Finitely many minimal primes) + ($R_M$ domain for all maximal $M$) $\Rightarrow$ ($R$ = product of domains)

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

We are doing a homework problem for our commutative algebra class, which asks us to prove:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ containing finitely many minimal prime ideals $P_1, \dots, P_n$.  If in addition $R$ satisfies that $R_M$ (the localization of $R$ at $M$) is a domain for all maximal ideals $M \subset R$, then $$ R \cong \frac{R}{P_1} \times \dots \times \frac{R}{P_n}. $$

If we could show that $R$ is Artinian, then we would be done by a result from class.  But we think we don't have enough to show this.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $i \neq j$, we deduce that $P_i+P_j$ is not contained in any maximal ideal: Assume $P_i+P_j \subset M$, then $R_M$ has at least two minimal primes - namely $P_i$ and $P_j$ - and is thus not a domain.

So $P_i+P_j=R$ for $i \neq j$. This is precisely what we need for the Chinese Remainder Theorem, hence we are done.

Note that $\bigcap_{1 \leq i \leq n} P_i$ is the nil-radical of $R$, but $R$ is reduced, since it is locally reduced.

By the way: Your conclusion, that there only finitely many maximal ideals, is plain wrong. For example, $R=\mathbb Z$ clearly satisfies all the assumptions and has infinitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: You are right about my statement about maximal ideals.  I will correct this error.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is obvious, but why does $P_i + P_j \subset M$ imply $P_i$ and $P_j$ are in $M$ (which is my interpretation of your statement, if I am correct that you mean the extensions of $P_i$ and $P_j$ are minimal primes in $R_M$)?

Comment: $P_i \subset P_i+P_j$.

Comment: Yes, I am being stupid, thank you.

Comment: Oh, another question.  So by the CRT, $$ \frac{R}{P_1 \dots P_n} \cong \frac{R}{P_1} \times \dots \times \frac{R}{P_n}. $$  How do we know $R/P_1...P_n \cong R$?

Comment: In my answer, I have already explained why $P_1 \dotsc P_n=0$. Note that in any case $P_1 \dotsc P_n \subset P_1 \cap \dotsb \cap P_n$ (We even have equality in this case, but we do not even need this for the argument).

Comment: I am trying to follow your argument:  We know $R_M$ has no nilpotents.  So let $x \in \bigcap p_i \subset M$ be a nonzero nilpotent.  This would be a contradiction so long as we show $x \neq 0 \in R_M$.  This is equivalent to saying there is no $u \notin M$ such that $xu = 0 \in R$.  I cannot see why this is so.

Comment: $R_M$ is reduced for **all** $M$: Let $x \neq 0$ be nilpotent, then $x \neq 0$ in some $R_M$, hence this $R_M$ has nilpotents. Contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38843/discussion-between-doug-and-moos).